# How to close a lightbox2 modal form after hitting a button in the

Tags: 7, javascript

I would like to have all delete pages in a modal form in Drupal 7. For this I choosed Lightbox2. if this can be achieved in another module this is also ok. In a view I add

```
rel="lightframe"
```

to the link for a node can be deleted. This is working perfect. The window is now opened in a modal form.

There are two buttons on this form. Confirm or Cancel

I rewrote the cancel button with hook form_alter:

```
 $form['actions']['cancel'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Cancel'), 
      '#attributes' => array('onclick' => 'parent.Lightbox.end();'),           
      );
```

This works good.

For the Submit button I do not get it working correctly
The code:

```
 $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Verwijderen'), 
      '#attributes' => array('onclick' => 'parent.Lightbox.end();'),           
      );
```

This will close the window but:
1) not executing the orginal action of deleting the node
This can be done with

```
 '#attributes' => array('onsubmit' => 'return TRUE', ),
```

but then the window is not closed.
2) not refreshing the original page.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Are you using Drupal 8 or 7?

Comment: Sorry forget to mension. Drupal 7

Comment: If it's any help, in D8 you can set the submission button as an AJAX callback and make it return AJAX commands that will be executed when the submission is completed (such as closing the modal).

Comment: Hi Eyal, how to do "set the submission button as an ajax callback and make it return AJAX commands"?

Comment: I don't know how to do it in drupal 7

Comment: Does anybody has another suggestion?